# How to accessicon from images using position in XAML style sheet

Tags: xaml, windows-phone

How to accessicon from images using position in  XAML style sheet

Like I have below image and I want to access icon at 2 row and 2 column

By using XAML style sheet any idea.

http://www.evohosting.co.uk/blog/wp-content/uploads/2011/07/blue.jpg

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

That image is not exactly conducive to being split up (some of the shadows overlap the icons below), but if you want to do it you can:

1. Create a class that has a method that returns an icon from the icon sheet given a row and column
2. Create a converter that calls that method and use it as the `Source` binding of an `Image`.

This class takes the source image and the width and height of each icon. Given a row and column index, the `GetIcon` function calculates the X and Y position of the icon and returns a `CroppedBitmap` containing the icon. The icons you ask for are cached so you don't end up creating the same icon multiple times.

```
public class IconSheet
{
    public BitmapImage SheetSource;

    private int iconWidth, iconHeight;

    private Dictionary<Tuple<int, int>, CroppedBitmap> cache =
                    new Dictionary<Tuple<int, int>, CroppedBitmap>();

    public IconSheet( BitmapImage sheetSource, int iconWidth, int iconHeight )
    {
        SheetSource = sheetSource;
        this.iconWidth = iconWidth;
        this.iconHeight = iconHeight;
    }

    public BitmapSource GetIcon( int row, int column )
    {
        var key = Tuple.Create( row, column );
        if( !cache.ContainsKey( key ) )
        {
            cache.Add( key, new CroppedBitmap( SheetSource, new Int32Rect(
                    column * iconWidth, row * iconHeight, iconWidth, iconHeight ) ) );
        }
        return cache[key];
    }
}
```

Next we create an `IValueConverter` that takes the `IconSheet` as a value and the row and column as its parameter (formatted as a string `"row,col"`). It calls the `GetIcon` method with the row and column which returns the `BitmapSource` we can use as the `Source` of our `Image`.

```
[ValueConversion( typeof( BitmapImage ), typeof( BitmapSource ) )]
public class IconSheetIndexer : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert( object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture )
    {
        var iconSheet = (value as IconSheet);
        var coords = (parameter as String).Split( ',' ).Select( s => int.Parse( s.Trim() ) ).ToList();
        return iconSheet.GetIcon( coords[0], coords[1] );
    }

    public object ConvertBack( object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture )
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

In the XAML, we'll define the three parameters our constructor takes - the icon sheet as a `BitmapImage` and the width and height of each icon. We'll also define the converter as a resource.

```
<Window.Resources>
    <BitmapImage x:Key="iconSheetSource" UriSource="blue.jpg" />
    <sys:Int32 x:Key="iconWidth">95</sys:Int32>
    <sys:Int32 x:Key="iconHeight">95</sys:Int32>
    <local:IconSheetIndexer x:Key="iconSheetIndexer"/>
</Window.Resources>
```

In code-behind, create the IconSheet using the parameters we defined in the XAML resources:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public IconSheet IconSheet { get; private set; }
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        IconSheet = new IconSheet( this.FindResource( "iconSheetSource" ) as BitmapImage,
            (int)this.FindResource( "iconWidth" ),
            (int)this.FindResource( "iconHeight" ) );

        this.DataContext = this;
    }
}
```

Then if you want to use, for example, the icon at row 1, column 3:

```
<Image Source="{Binding IconSheet, Converter={StaticResource iconSheetIndexer}, ConverterParameter='1,3'}" Stretch="None"/>
```

Results (as a `UniformGrid` with each of the 16 icons bound to an `Image`):

[image: Example app]